# Type cannot conform to Decodable but it actually is

Tags: swift, codable, swift-protocols, decodable

I have a Type called ObjectAPIModel that explicitly conforms to the Codable protocol. I also do have a function which receives some data and calls another function to decode any JSON to a specified type. But if I call decodeJSON() it shows an error that ObjectAPIModel does not conform to Decodable. Can anyone help?

```
struct ObjectAPIModel: Codable {
    
    let objectID: Int
    var primaryImage: String
    var title: String
    var department: String
}
```

```
func decodeJSON<T: Decodable>(data: Data, ofType: T) -> Result<T, APIError> {
        
    let decodedObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    if decodedObject == nil {
        return .failure(APIError.emptyResponse)
    } else {
        return .success(decodedObject!)
    }
}
```

```
let result = decodeJSON(data: unwrappedData, ofType: ObjectAPIModel)
```

Error I receive: "Type 'ObjectAPIModel.Type' cannot conform to 'Decodable'"

Comment: Use ObjectAPIModel.self instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following line

```
func decodeJSON<T: Decodable>(data: Data, ofType: T) -> Result<T, APIError>
```

the parameter `ofType` is declared to be an *instance* of `T` and you are trying to pass the type meta object. Change the declaration as follows:

```
func decodeJSON<T: Decodable>(data: Data, ofType: T.Type) -> Result<T, APIError>
//                                                  ^^^^
```

Also, when you call `decodeJSON` you can't use a bare type name, you have to put `ObjectAPIModel.self` i.e.

```
let result = decodeJSON(data: unwrappedData, ofType: ObjectAPIModel.self)
//                                                                  ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it! I also had to change the call to "decodeJSON(data: unwrappedData, ofType: ObjectAPIModel.self)" as @JoakimDanielson mentioned.

Comment: @olvrwn Oh yes, forgot about that issue. I'll add it to the answer.